# how to read multiple input data listed on the same line of a file in python

Tags: python

I have a file input.dat with contents:

```
1.00000000   1.00000000   0.00000000   0.10000000        12        12     50000           2
```

I want to read these values and assign them to variables a1 to a8 respectively.

I try:

```
with open("input_params.dat","r") as inpfl:
    a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8 = inpfl.read()
```

and get the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 8)
```

How can I modify read() to do what I want?

I also need a1,..., a8 to be floats and integers respectively and not string variables. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: `inpfl.read().split()`

Comment: Do not use `a1`, `a2`, ..., `a8`.  Either use sensible names or use a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just use below code:

```
f = open('1.txt' , 'r')
lines = f.read().split(" ")
```

so you have list of values and you can take it in variable if you want like below:
`a = lines[0]`, `b = lines[1]` and so on.

You can use `a1,a2,a3 = f.read().split(" ")` if you want it in variables. Provided you have exact number of variables as values in file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, it does help in case I want the variables on a list

Comment: You can use a1,a2,a3 = f.read().split(" ") if you want it in variables.

Comment: yes, it was mentioned above and it's what I need. Thanks again

Comment: This way, a1 to a8 are string variables. I need them to be floats and integers respectively. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: As your file will always return string when you read from it, you will have to manually convert the values accordingly. I think all you can convert all values to the float as 12.0 is as good as 12. You can use a1,a2,a3...= float(f.read().split(" ")). If you want it to be int and float resp then you have to manually do float() or int()